# On Virtual Private Server, ports are not reachable from the internet although no firewall is enabled

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, ufw

I have a newly set up virtual private server running Ubuntu 22.04. `ufw`  is still disabled, `iptables -L` tells me all chains have the ACCEPT default policy, no specific rules are defined. So I'd expect all ports to be open to the internet. I have a process listening on some port, this is confirmed by `ss -lte`.

However, I cannot reach this port from the internet and get "connection refused" when trying. `nmap` tells me the only open ports on the server are 22 for `ssh` and 80 for `http`, both of which I did not open.

Hosting provider support staff told me they do not have any kind of firewall or access restriction enabled.

So I'm out of my wits, I guess I'm missing something. What do I have to do to enable access to a specifc port? Why is it that ports 22 and 80 are open, but nothing else, when no firewall is running? Thanks for any advice!

Comment: nft list ruleset

Comment: @gapsf: ```nft list ruleset``` returns no output at all, so I guess there are no rules.

Comment: Wjat ptables-save outputs?

Comment: @gapsf: ```iptables-save``` outputs nothing. I don't think it's a firewall on the server; I'm quite sure there is none.

Comment: Check the host you connecting from, your routers other divices on your side. Also I guess its hosting filtering despite whayt they says